# Queue Abstract Data Type - Float Elements

Tags: language-agnostic, queue, abstract-data-type

How would you design a queue abstract data type for float elements in C (or any preferred language), with operations for enqueue, dequeue, and empty? The dequeue operation should remove the element and returns its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java, I came up with a quick and dirty solution as follows:

```
 public class QueueOps {

    private ArrayList<Float> queueReference;

    public QueueOps(){
        queueReference = new ArrayList<Float>();
    }

    public void enqueue(float number){
        queueReference.add(number);
    }

    public float dequeue(){
        float number = queueReference.get(0);
        queueReference.remove(0);
        queueReference.trimToSize();
        return number;
    }

    public void empty(){
        queueReference.clear();
    }
}
```